# PHP. How do I move html text to a different area?

Tags: php, html, css, drupal, drupal-7

**How can I move my intro text shown in step 2 to the same place in step 1?**

To see the intro text visit - [my page](http://www.workbooks.com/sales-performance-calculator) and click "Get started now".

Then click > Next step

You'll see the text:

> Over the next few steps we’ll ask you to rate your current sales and marketing performance and then estimate your future rating with a new CRM platform that meets your business needs and requirements.

This is the text which I'd like to remove and add in the same place above the first step (Step 1 (of 7) - Current Business Figures.

This line is found on line 9 in values.php see JSFiddle - [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arf1z13w/).

```
$wb_spc_array['sections'][] = array("key" => "new-business-generating", "name" => "New Business Generating", "type" => "sales", "intro" => "<p>Over the next few steps we’ll ask you to rate your current sales and marketing performance and then estimate your future rating with a new CRM platform that meets your business needs and requirements.</p>", "description" => "Rate your organisation on its ability to effectively market to new prospects, generate leads and then measure the ROI of marketing campaigns. We&rsquo;ve outlined some positive and negative indicators below to provide you with a benchmark.", "body" => "
```

The remainder of the page seems to be styled in wb_spc.module, see a JSFiddle of this - [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bmzox5vL/).

How can I make this work?

Comment: for me the page doesn't load

Comment: Fixed! Apologies, I had linked to my VM url.